# Uploading JSON Object to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have to "POST" JSON Objects to server via ajax calls.

I'm using :

`data : { fieldName : JSONObject }`

for the data part in the ajax call.
The data is uploaded fine, as a JSON. But it takes the following form :

`{ "0" : {key,value} , "1" : {key,value} ... };`

How to get rid of the "0","1",etc. that are being added automatically? Is it something that I can handle at the client side, or is it the server side code that is responsible for this? As far as I understand, it's the server side code.

---

EDIT :

Response Received :

`[
    {
        "students": {
            "0": {
                "id": "101",
                "name": "A"
            },
            "1": {
                "id": "102",
                "name": "B"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "103",
                "name": "C"
            },
            "3": {
                "id": "104",
                "name": "D"
            }
        }
    }
]`

JSONObject :

`[
    {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": 103,
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": 104,
        "name": "D"
    }
]`

Just a guess, is it because the JSONObject is an array , ie `[]` are causing the probs? Meanwhile I'll just test the same without the `[]`.

Comment: What is in `JSONObject` ?

Comment: The JSON that I want to POST.

Comment: If it's JSON, it must be a **string**, not an object.

Comment: Do `JSON.stringify( data )` to encode the object using JSON

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON server-side ?

Comment: `{ "0" : {key,value} , "1" : {key,value} ... };` is not valid... please post the actual response and how your JSONObject looks like.

Comment: This is strange, the response is not an exact match to your `JSONObject`. I guess somebody wrote a JSON Parser by hand and messed this up. You should take a look into the server side code and see how the request is handled.

Comment: @Christoph just to add a bit, the `students` is the data object on the server side to which I want to upload a JSON.

Comment: I tested using python, [here](http://pastebin.com/Gygirpb8), and it works as expected.

Comment: Yah, this is how it should look like. What did you use before?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(object);` to convert your JavaScript object into a JSON String.

Comment: no need, jQuery does this automatically... the JSONObject is in the wrong format, that's all